# zsh showing weired numbers instead ofcharacters

Tags: macos, character-encoding, terminal, hex, zsh

when I start to type whitespace, dot, comma in zsh it change the characters to their hex equivalent. how can I change that?

[image: typeing space, dot, comma in zsh]

Comment: it doesn't help. still the problem exists

Comment: Does the problem persist if you start a new instance of *zsh* in the terminal with `zsh -f`? (`-f` prevents the loading of most configuration files)

Comment: @Adaephon : yes the problem remains with -f option.

Comment: try `stty sane ; tput rs1`

Comment: @lolesque no help :(